# Create a generic class that can queue a job for data to be pushed to an external API

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am developing a Laravel project from the beginning, and I want to create a generic class that can queue a job for data to be pushed to an external API. How can I do that? I am new to queues and jobs.

Following Code is what I tried. I created the following Job class and called it where I need to push data to external APIs. This worked for me. But I am open to other solutions.

```
    class ApiPushService implements ShouldQueue
{

    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, Queueable;

    protected $endpoint;
    protected $data;

    /**
     * ApiPushService constructor.
     * @param $endpoint
     * @param $data
     */
    public function __construct($endpoint, $data)
    {
        $this->endpoint = $endpoint;
        $this->data = $data;
    }


    /**
     * @param Client $guzzleClient
     */
    public function handle(Client $guzzleClient)
    {
        //get external api url
        $url = $this->endpoint;

        try {
            $response = $guzzleClient->request('POST', $url, [
                'headers' => array("Content-Type" => "application/json"),
                'json' => $this->data
            ]);
        } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
            Log::error("ApiPushService (handle): Guzzle Bad Response Exception : " . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            Log::error("ApiPushService (handle): Guzzle Request Exception : " . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
            Log::error("ApiPushService (handle): Guzzle  Exception : " . $e->getMessage());
        }

        if ($response->getStatusCode() != 200) {
            Log::info("ApiPushService (handle): Endpoint Response : ",
                json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true));
        } else {
            Log::error("ApiPushService (handle): Guzzle Request error : ",
                json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the two topics?

Comment: @Namoshek: yes mate. I went through the documentation and figured out.

Comment: Updated the question with what I did. not sure this is the best way but this worked for me.